# Using my email and webpage screenshots in my thesis

Tags: publications, copyright

My research is about data-driven marketing methods and applying those methods in education. In my PhD thesis, I use some screenshots of commercial emails in my email box from companies such as Amazon, Les Mills, etc. An example: [image]

I also used some screenshots from part of a webpage from companies such as Mailchimp. An example: [image]
I have a copyright question: Do I need to seek permission for using these images?

P.S. I study at the University of South Australia

Comment: You're probably better off asking at https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Related: [Legality of screenshot of another website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/41115/92089),  [Using a software screenshot in a paper](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10100/68109), [How does copyright work on screen captures?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26526/68109).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does copyright work on screen captures?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26526/how-does-copyright-work-on-screen-captures)